# What is Pilates and what are some good resources on it?

Tags: pilates

What is the Pilates? 
What kind of training/equipment does it involve?
Can beginners do Pilates?
Are there any good resources in terms of book/websites on Pilates?

Comment: Yes, beginners can do Pilates. As for what it is, have you searched already? There's a lot of resources available.

Comment: Try to run your posts through a spell checker next time. Also its better to ask more specific questions rather than open ended ones. A simple Google search can answer a lot of the questions you're asking. The first one being [wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilates)

Comment: possible wiki question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pilates are full body exercises that focus on strengthening your bodies inner core.  The Pilates exercises that I have done before require no additional equipment.  You don't need any special training, however they can be rather challenging! All you need is a good video.

Speaking of which, try this one, which is so appropriately named [POP Pilates for Beginners - Total Body Workout](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCg_gh_fppI).

Answer (score 4):

> “In 10 sessions you will feel the difference, in 20 sessions you will
>   see the difference, and in 30 you will have a new body.”
>   - Joseph Pilates

Pilates was "invented" by Joseph Pilates, a German physical-culturist who, during the first half of the last century, came up with a system of core exercises that strengthen both the human body and mind. He was convinced that the health of these were interrelated. He published several books and gained more and more attention. In recent years the term "Pilates" has entered the mainstream and equipment is often both over-priced and over-rated...

Here is some advice for beginners (taken from [this Pilates article](http://queencheap.com/awesome-deals/pilates-reformer-for-cheap-the-alternative-to-plastic-surgery)):

1. Go to a Pilates studio.  Understand you need to first work with a professional.  You will not get the results or body/mind awareness without this key step. So budget for this, it’s not forever...
2. Begin to buy some smaller home equipment.  After 2-3 months of working with your pilates trainer, you’ll have great body knowledge and are ready for some home equipment.  It is my recommendation to continue working with your trainer at least once-twice a week and to now supplement your other workouts at home.

In the above resource you'll also find that you don't have to buy the $3,000 reformer machines. There are several cheap (approx $100-$150) alternatives on Amazon. Once you have your new machine, you’re going to want a trainer, and well trainers are not cheap.  So here is what you do: subscribe to [Pilates Anytime](http://www.pilatesanytime.com).  It is a great website with hundreds of free pilates reformer classes.